# Upload default image if user didn't upload any

Tags: php, function, file-upload

I have a piece of code from upload.php

```
$uploaddir = '../photo/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    //...
}
```

How can I add a function that if user didn't upload an image, then a default image is uploaded?

Comment: Why not use a default image URL so you don't upload it to each user. So if user has an image, show that one. If he doesn't just use the default one. Right...?

Comment: `if (upload_successful()) { move_uploaded_file() } else { copy($default_image); }`

Comment: Yes, it can by default url

Answer (score 0):

You should first check `$_FILES['userfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK`
if it's not `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, then something went wrong.
A list of errors can be found here: [file-upload.errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Example:

```
$uploaddir = '../photo/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    /** do stuff **/
  }
} else {
  echo "An error occurred with your upload.<br>";

  switch($_FILES['userfile']['error']) { 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
      echo "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
      echo "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
      echo "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
      echo "No file was uploaded"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
      echo "Missing a temporary folder"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
      echo "Failed to write file to disk"; 
      break; 
    case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
      echo "File upload stopped by extension"; 
      break; 
    default: 
      $message = "Unknown upload error"; 
      break; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my answer. It's [CodeAngry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451110/codeangry)'s comment:

*Why not use a default image URL so you don't upload it to each user. So if user has an image, show that one. If he doesn't just use the default one*

It's more efficient to only store an image that the user explicitly choose to upload. If the user didn't upload it, then when you have to show it do something like this:

PHP

```
//assumimg you stored the image with user_id as name
$path_to_image = "img/" . $user_id . ".jpg";
$image = (file_exists($path_to_image)) ? $path_to_image : $default_image_path;
```

HTML

```
<img src="<?=$image?>" alt="" />
```

Plus it will save you disk space!

Comment: I just put this $uploadfile = "../photo/nophoto.png"; and if image didnt upload from user side, then it just give ar url, something like your thing, Okey, this job is done, thx to all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also:
(of course under echo "" in case of php)

```
// Replace source with other image in case user didn't upload any photo
$('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});

// Or, hide the 'broken image' 
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```